# Passagem por referencia imprimindo lixo no vetor

Tags: array, c++, funções, passagem-por-referência

Pessoal fiz um código simples porém estou com um problema. Fiz uma função "aumentar" para incrementar o tamanho de um vetor; A função recebe o vetor e passa os valores desse vetor para um vetor auxiliar. Assim posso deletar o vetor, alocar o novo tamanho e recuperar os valores dela pq foram salvos no vetor aux. O problema é que ele ta imprimindo lixo. Se eu imprimir o vetor dentro da função sai tudo certo mas na main sai errado. Alguém pode ajudar? Segue o codigo:

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void aumentar(int *vetor, int tam){
    int *aux, i;

    aux= new int[tam];

    for(i=0; i<tam; i++){
        aux[i]=vetor[i];
    }

    cout<<"aux:"<<endl;
    for(i=0; i<tam; i++){
        cout<<aux[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    delete []vetor;

    vetor = new int[11];

    for(i=0; i<tam; i++){
        vetor[i]=aux[i];
    }

    vetor[tam]=10;

    for(i=0; i<11; i++){
        cout<<vetor[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;

}

int main(){
    int *vetor, i;

    vetor = new int[10];

    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        vetor[i]=i;
    }

    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        cout<<vetor[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    aumentar(vetor,10);

    cout<<"Resultado"<<endl;

    for(i=0; i<11; i++){
        cout<<vetor[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void aumentar(int *vetor, int tam)
```

Nesta função, `int *vetor` é um **ponteiro** passado por **cópia**, e não por referência. Ele somente recebe o valor da memória alocada anteriormente. Isso significa que `vetor` na função `main` e `vetor` na função `aumentar` estão apontando para o mesmo endereço de memória mas eles não são o **mesmo** ponteiro.

Quando você modifica `vetor` dentro da função `aumentar`

```
delete []vetor;
vetor = new int[11];
```

ele agora aponta para um lugar diferente na memória. Mas essa é uma variável na pilha; uma cópia de `vetor` na função `main`! `vetor` é local para a função que você está.

O que você quer é uma **referência**:

```
void aumentar(int *& vetor, int tam)
```

Comment: é isso mesmo! Obrigado!